# Does k8 update environment variables when secrets change?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, signals, kubernetes-secrets

While running kubernetes clusters, I've noticed that when a secret's value is changed [pods that use it as an environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) are *not* rebuilt and my applications *don't* receive a `SIGTERM` event.

While I know it's technically possible to update the environment of a running process using something like [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/), this is a horrible thing to do and I assume k8s doesn't do this.

Is there a signal that is sent to an effected process when this situation occurs, or some other way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nor does any such thing happen on `ConfigMap` mounts, env-var injection, or any other situation; signals are sent to your process only as a side-effect of Pod termination

There are [innumerable](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=kubernetes+reload+configmap+secret&atb=v73-4_q&ia=web) solutions to [do rolling update on `ConfigMap` or `Secret` change](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader#readme) but you have to configure what you would want your cluster to do and under what circumstances, because there is no way that a one-size-fits-all solution would work in all the ways that kubernetes is used in the world

Comment: This is not fully true, mounts of both Secrets and ConfigMaps do update in-place on changes. But most apps don't reload config files on change.